# TensorFlow の tf.squeeze はどのような処理を行うものでしょうか

Tags: python, tensorflow

tf.squeezeはどのような処理を行うものでしょうか？
また，それを用いた下記のコードによって形成されるp_inputsのshapeはどのようになるでしょうか？ご教授願えれば幸いです．よろしくお願いいたします．

```
batch_num = 10
step_num = 2000
elem_num = 26

p_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_num, step_num, elem_num])
p_inputs = [tf.squeeze(t, [1]) for t in tf.split(1, step_num, p_input)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tf.squeezeはsizeが1の次元を削除し次元数を減らすAPIとなります。
第二引数を指定した場合は指定したindexの次元かつそこがsizeが1であるならば次元数を減らします。

ご提示の例の場合tは
[batch_num, step_num, elem_num]のstep_num分split
つまり[batch_num, 1, elem_num]の形となりますので。

上記tをtf.squeeze(t, [1])にかけるということは
「indexが1でそこが次元数1であるならばその次元を削除する。」となりますので
[batch_num, elem_num]のshapeのTensorが出力される事になります。

第二引数を指定し、かつそこがsize 1でない場合はエラーが出るかと思います。
詳細は以下となります。
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#squeeze